# How to disable Sitecore Analytics entirely

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

We are experiencing cpu problems on our production servers. After profiling with the jetbrains cpu profiler, we have noticed that some functions in the assembly `Sitecore.Analytics` were executed.

This is somewhat strange because we have disabled all analytics related configuration in de config files.

After looking into the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` we noticed that there are still a lot of `Sitecore.Analytics` related configurations in this config while these are deactivated in our config files.

For example

In the file `/App_Config/Include/EventHandlers.config` the configuration looks like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
 <sitecore>
   <events timingLevel="custom">
   </events>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

When looking into the `showconfig.aspx` it looks something like this:

```
<events timingLevel="custom">
<event name="forms:save"/>
<event name="item:saved">
            <handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics" method="OnItemSaved"/>
            <handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.Items.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Automation.MarketingAutomation" method="OnAutomationStateChanged"/>
        </event>
        <event name="item:deleted">
            <handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Data.Items.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Automation.MarketingAutomation" method="OnAutomationStateChanged"/>
        </event>
        <event name="media:request">
            <handler type="Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics" method="OnMediaRequest"/>
        </event>
</events>
```

Does anyone has an idea why these are still returning in the `showconfig.aspx`?
Is there a way to fully delete/disable the sitecore analytics module?

Comment: Just an FYI, there are some Sitecore features which rely on Analytics being active. One that immediately comes to mind is the IP geo-coding. So if you are using that feature to drive geographic-based content, it will fail when Analytics is disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Rename the 3 configuration files for Sitecore.Analytics in your /App_Config/Include directory to something other than *.config

The 3 files are:

- Sitecore.Analytics.config
- Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config
- Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.config

(could vary a little bit by version, but they all start with Sitecore.Analytics).

Rename them to something like:

- Sitecore.Analytics.config.disabled
- Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config.disabled
- Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.config.disabled

Answer (score 2):

> (could vary a little bit by version, but they all start with Sitecore.Analytics).

Until sitecore version 72, there are only 3 files with Sitecore.Analytics prefix. In version 75, there are 17 and in version 8 there are 20 config files with Sitecore.Analytics prefix.

I used to confirm with sitecore support that you can change the setting of Analytics.Enabled in Sitecore.Analytics.config will disable Analytics

```
<setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="false" />
```

Or only rename one file Sitecore.Analytics.config which contain this setting.

Comment: Note that (for Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150121) the experience analytics module doesn't take this setting into account: _ExperienceAnalytics Reduce subsystem is not initialized as Analytics is disabled_ shows up in log file, but its _SegmentInitializer_ throws an exception a few lines later. Also accessing the Sitecore Launchpad tries to get aggregation stats through a remote call, which cause another exception.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to User WFFM ?
There also analytics part:
Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.config

and disabling it causes this fault:

> 22992 14:49:10 WARN  Value cannot be null. Parameter name: owner
>   Exception: System.ArgumentNullException Message: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: owner Source: Sitecore.Kernel    at
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String
>   argumentName)    at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Warn(String message,
>   Object owner)    at Sitecore.WFFM.Core.Extensions.Warn.IsNull(Object
>   obj, String name)    at
>   Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.AnalyticsTracker.get_SessionId()    at
>   Sitecore.Form.Core.FormDataHandler.ExecuteSaveActions(ID formId,
>   ControlResult[] fields, ActionDefinition[] actions)    at
>   Sitecore.Form.Core.FormDataHandler.ProcessData(SimpleForm form,
>   ControlResult[] fields, ActionDefinition[] actions)

So it cannot be disabled.