# Disable Analytics in Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, sitecore8

I have a Sitecore Experience Platform (Sitecore version 8 in layman terms) that I would like to NOT use the Analytics. When I look at Sitecore Experience, analytics are all throughout. I would like to disable Analytics in a "clean" way, but for Sitecore 8 as I understand it approach is different. What is the correct approach?

Note: Yes, I know about:

`<setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="false" />`

And yes, I saw the seemingly related question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300872/how-to-disable-sitecore-analytics-entirely/27986833#answer-27986833).

Thank you in advance!!
Sasha

Comment: Setting that value works for me in dev, there is one error on startup which you can remove by disabling all in ExperienceAnalytics folder. Not sure if this will suffice long term though... suggest you clarify with Sitecore Support directly for definitive answer.

Comment: @jammykam: Kamruz, I have ran it by Sitecore Support. The answer was not helpful to me, hence I was asking it here. Quote: "Sitecore 8 was designed as a connected platform and was not tested thoroughly with xDB (analytics) functionality disabled, so Sitecore is not guaranteed to work without xDB. Anyway, we have registered a request to have this configuration fully supported. We will let you know as soon as it is implemented."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Sasha, good to know the official stance. Will make some enquiries but I heard the same thing through the grapevine...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Sitecore KB article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/296641) which looks like it was published after the initial question mentions only the

```
<setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="false" />
```

line mentioned above in `/App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Analytics.config`, as well as commenting out / removing the connection strings in `/App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config`.

```
<add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/analytics" />
<add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_live" />
<add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_history" />
<add name="tracking.contact" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_contact" />
<add name="reporting" connectionString="user id=user;password=password;Data Source=(server);Database=Sitecore_Analytics" />
```

It also outlines the numerous limitations which take affect because of the lack of xDB.

---

This seems to be a popular question/answer, so some updated info: for Sitecore 8.1 without xDB, this is now called "[CMS-only mode](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/experience_management/experience_management_an_overview)" and can be enabled in a similar way - by setting `Xdb.enabled` to "false" in Sitecore.Xdb.config.

Comment: Spurious errors may occur in log and With Web Forms for Marketers you need to adjust, I think it is still not really advisable to do on production. but nice there is a kb article!

Comment: Note that the setting was renamed in Sitecore 8.1. It is now called Xdb.Enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I use a dev environment where I delete all the Analytics files in the App_Config/include folder, Sitecore.Analytics.*.config instead of delete you can also rename to .disabled

It works for me But not sure of there are no issue. I also don't need any analytics connectionstring. But i don't go live with that deleted config.

Edit:
It is not possible say Sitecore lots of errors in log, and some functions are broken there is a future request to make it possible in future versions.

Comment: Jan, this is what I ran into as well. Hence decided to ask here.

Comment: A related issue: Sitecore 8.0 without Analytics can make your package installer goes in never ending loop http://sitecorejourney.nileshthakkar.in/2015/01/is-your-sitecore-8-stuck-up-while.html

Answer (score 1):

We got the same issue, Here are some points for the consideration.

1. Sitecore later version not support below tag.

For later version - After Sitecore 8.1 we can plan the same setting by below section.
Go to Sitecore.Xdb.config and update the **setting Xdb.Enabled** value to true

2. for CD server - Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config - Host name should be provided.

We have tried above two options but the issue was not resolved.

Finally - once we restart the IIS then it works.

Point is this may occur again - Will provide the full RCA if found any.